# Applying a windowfunction discards events in the result

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to count the elements in a stream while enriching the result with the end time of the window.

The events are received from Kafka using kafka10 consumer provided by flink. EventTime is used. 
A simple KeyedStream.count( ... ) works fine. 
The stream has a length of 4 minutes. By using a time window of 3 minutes only one output is received. There should be two. The results are written using a BucketingSink.

```scala
val count = stream.map( m => (m.getContext, 1) )
    .keyBy( 0 )
    .timeWindow( Time.minutes(3) )
    .apply( new EndTimeWindow() )
    .map( new JsonMapper() )
count.addSink( countSink )
```

```
class EndTimeWindow extends WindowFunction[(String,Int),(String, Int),Tuple, TimeWindow]{
    override def apply(key: Tuple, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[(String, Int)], out: Collector[(String, Int)]): Unit =  {
        var sum: Int = 0
        for( value <-input ) {
            sum = sum + value._2;
        }
        out.collect( (window.getEnd.toString, new Integer(sum ) ))
    }
}
```

By using a time window of 3 minutes only one output with a smaller amount of events is received. There should be two outputs.

Comment: I'm very sure about your problem. Why are there should be two outputs ?

Comment: The first window output should sum up the number of events from e.g. start to minute 3 and the second one from minute 3 to minute 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more precise, an event time window closes when a suitable watermark arrives -- which, with a bounded-out-of-orderness watermark generator, will happen (1) if an event arrives that is sufficiently outside the window, or (2) if the events are coming from a finite source that reaches its end, because in that case Flink will send a watermark with a timestamp of Long.MAX_VALUE that will close all open event time windows. However, with Kafka as your source, that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think, I know what went wrong. The mistake happens, because I thought wrong about the problem.
Since I'm using Eventtime, the windows close, when an event arrives that has a timestamp greater than the window end time. When the stream ends there arrives no element anymore. It follows, that the window never closes.